# Integration Of Multischema to Single Schema

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

Our application was deployed in Multiple Schema based on the Locations.

Now we are going to merge the data of different databases to single database of MySql

As I am new to Database Migration , I really likes to take advice of experts.

1) Any good tools can be used for this process.

2) What are the precautions to be done for this.

The application is in Spring,Hibernate, Java

Database is MySql